# How to get the Id of an element in a list object in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all the IDs of the list that I declare, how can I do it?

I'm trying to do this and then in the JavaScript I want to put all these values in a list. Don't pay attention to the alert, it's used to see what is the id that it gets.

```js
function getIDs() {
  for (i = 1; i < document.getElementById("myUL1").getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++) {
    var e = document.getElementById(i).value;
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL1">
  <li id=1 value=A>First</li>
  <li id=2 value=B>Second</li>
  <li id=3 value=C>Third</li>
  <li id=4 value=D>Fourth</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="getIDs()" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Test</button>
```

Comment: `<li>` element nodes do not have a "value" property. You can put a "value" attribute on an `<li>` but you have to fetch it with `.getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to improve the following

- To iterate over all the elements, condition in for loop should be  `i <=`
- `li` element does not have `value` property, use `getAttribute`

```js
function getIDs() {
  
 for(i = 1; i <= document.getElementById("myUL1").getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++){
  var e = document.getElementById(i).getAttribute("value");
  console.log(e);
 }
 
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL1">
  <li id=1 value=A>First</li>
  <li id=2 value=B>Second</li>
  <li id=3 value=C>Third</li>
  <li id=4 value=D>Fourth</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="getIDs()" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Test</button>
```

**EDIT**

Modified the example, to give better insight on how to retrieve id (from comments)

```js
function getIDs() {
  var lis = document.getElementById("myUL1").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (li of lis) {
    console.log(li.getAttribute("id")); // paints id
    console.log(li.getAttribute("value")); // paints value
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL1">
  <li id="myUL1-Li1" value=A>First</li>
  <li id="myUL1-Li2" value=B>Second</li>
  <li id="myUL1-Li3" value=C>Third</li>
  <li id="myUL1-Li4" value=D>Fourth</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="getIDs()" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Test</button>
```

Comment: the problem is that I want the IDs of each element of the list

Comment: change 'getAttribute("value");' to 'getAttribute("id");' in his code and you will get what you want @LiquidSnake. But please read what he is doing and adjust the code a little bit to what you need. Everything Nikhil Aggarwal said is correct and not worth to down vote his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already reference elements using `document...getElementsByTagName("li")` there is no need to use `getElementById()`.

Also `li` don't have valid `value` property if you need to persists arbitrary data use [custom `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which can be retrieved using [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

```js
function getIDs() {
  var elements = document.getElementById("myUL1").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var elem = elements[i];

    console.log(elem.id, elem.dataset.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL1">
  <li id="1" data-value="A">First</li>
  <li id="2" data-value="B">Second</li>
  <li id="3" data-value="C">Third</li>
  <li id="4" data-value="D">Fourth</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="getIDs()" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Test</button>
```